# Simple example of an initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I'm looking for a simple example of how to use the initializer list. Here's what I want to do:
I've got the following class:

```
class foo{
    public:
        void set_x(const int ix);
        void set_y(const int iy);
        void display();
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
};
```

I'd like to create an object of this class in the following way:

```
foo fooObj = {1, 2};
```

I know that it is possible with vector in C++11. How can I implement this kind of behaviour?

Comment: regular two-parameter-constructor will work fine, if it's an aggregate type then no actions are needed at all

Comment: [Doing nothing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/426aa6331b0851fb) is enough. `foo` is an aggregate.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake in my example. Variables should be private.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, a simple constructor will work:

```
foo(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
```

If the class were an even simpler *aggregate* (which yours would be if the data members were public) then you wouldn't even need that - this style of initialisation will initialise each member of an aggregate in turn.

For something more complicated, like `vector`, where the number of arguments can vary, you need to use an `initializer_list`. Include the header:

```
#include <initializer_list>
```

and a constructor

```
foo(std::initializer_list<int>);
```

The type acts like a container, with `begin()`, `end()` and `size()` functions to access its contents.